# Selenium manipulate Webdriver = true

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

For security purposes I was wondering if there is a way to manipulate the selenium webdriver(s) (firefox,chrome).

We run some tests and did some modifications but we were not able to get on the right track.

Is there a way to manipulate the selenium webdrivers, to make the selenium webdrivers looks like a 100% real browser?

We tried it to setup with a proxy server and add headers but the result is the same. Got blocked on a few websites which are using a selenium detection.

This is only a general question!
Are there aternatives related to selenium? webdrivers?

Thanks!

Normal Browser:

```
Navigator { permissions: Permissions, mimeTypes: MimeTypeArray, plugins: PluginArray, doNotTrack: "unspecified", battery: BatteryManager, oscpu: "Windows NT 10.0; WOW64", vendor: "", vendorSub: "", productSub: "20100101", cookieEnabled: true }
```

Selenium Firefox Driver:

```
Navigator { webdriver: true, mozContacts: ContactManager, permissions: Permissions, mimeTypes: MimeTypeArray, plugins: PluginArray, doNotTrack: "unspecified", battery: BatteryManager, oscpu: "Windows NT 10.0; WOW64", vendor: "", vendorSub: "" }
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver

Comment: Take a look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) I think it's what you need. The example shows how to manipulate the exposed javascript variables used in the detection of selenium.